# Google Identity Services Library Not Loading in JavaScript Application

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-api, google-identity

I'm encountering an issue with the Google Identity Services library not loading properly in my JavaScript application. I've followed the official documentation for integrating Google Identity Services, but the library initialization seems to be failing.

The issue is that the handleClientLoad function is being called, but it seems that the initClient callback is not executed, and I'm not seeing the corresponding console log message. The library doesn't appear to be loading correctly.

```
<!-- ... (head section) ... -->
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<script>
  const CLIENT_ID = "your_client_id_here"; // Replace with your actual client ID

  function handleClientLoad() {
    console.log("Initializing Google Identity Services...");
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: CLIENT_ID,
      callback: initClient
    });
    console.log("Initialization request sent.");
  }

  function initClient() {
    console.log("Initialization callback called...");
    // Further initialization logic
  }

  window.addEventListener('load', handleClientLoad);
</script>
<!-- ... (rest of the HTML) ... -->
```

Checked the Google Cloud project configuration to ensure the CLIENT_ID is correct.
Reviewed the official documentation for Google Identity Services.
Added additional console.log statements for debugging.

Comment: please add a link to the documentation you are following